# Regex result need to not match if the line include og tag

Tags: regex

How do I exclude a match if it includes `meta` or `og:image`?

I've tried this regex out:

```
(?!og\:image.*http:\/\/)((http:)(.*\.abc.com))
```

which should match:

```
<% Response.Redirect("http://campaign.abc.com/en/") %>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://campaign.abc.com/aaa/cookie.jpg" />
```

but not:

```
<a href="http://campaign.abc.com/en/"> abc.com </a>
```

Comment: not match:
<meta property="og:image" content="http://campaign.abc.com/aaa/cookie.jpg" />

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative look ahead assuming that "meta" and "og:image" are inside a tags "<>".

it depends on what application your'e going to use to apply regex, here's a sample via javascript which stops after one match:

Regex pattern:
`/<(?!.*(meta|og:image)).*>/g`

Code:

```js
var subject = $('#content').val();

var myArray = /<(?!.*(meta|og:image)).*>/g.exec(subject);

console.log(myArray);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="content">
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://campaign.abc.com/aaa/cookie.jpg" />
 <property="og:image" content="http://campaign.abc.com/aaa/cookie.jpg" />
 <% Response.Redirect("http://campaign.abc.com/en/") %>
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://campaign.abc.com/aaa/cookie.jpg" />
 <property="og:image" content="http://campaign.abc.com/aaa/cookie.jpg" />
</textarea>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```